# Parsing a formula with java poi doen't work

Tags: java, excel, parsing, apache-poi, formula

I need to complete an excel with some data. But one cell in the sheet is a formula so I'm working with the parseformula gived by the poi library but I have some problems with the formula that I want to use:

=IF((E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3) = 0;"";E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)

PS : all cells are in different lists

and the code is the following:

```
"IF(("+cellule_cm.get(ligne_excel)+"*1,5+"+cellule_td.get(ligne_excel)+"+"+
cellule_tp.get(ligne_excel)+"*2/3)=0;\"\";"+cellule_cm.get(ligne_excel)+"*1,5+"+cellule_td.get(ligne_excel)+"+"+cellule_tp.get(ligne_excel)+"*2/3)";
```

`ligne_excel` is the index of the line that i want to modify
`cellule_cm`, `cellule_td`, `cellule_tp` are my list of cell

when i run it throw me the exception :

> Parse error near char 23 ';' in specified formula
>   'IF((E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)=0;"";E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)'. Expected ',' or ')'

I don't understand why I can't parse 
Can you help me?

Comment: `Apache poi` needs the formula in English since all Excel files stores formulas in English notation. The translation to the locale is done by Excel GUI then. So instead of `1,5` it must be `1.5` and the parameter delimiter is comma and not semicolon. The function name `IF` is English already.

Comment: that's my boy big thanks to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Apache POI-documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html) POI only supports commas as separator for the arguments:

Section "**The basics**"

"Also note that only commas may be used to separate arguments, as per the Excel English style, alternate delimeters used in other localizations are not supported."

Comment: i have already try and that's the message : The specified formula '=IF((E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)=0;"";E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)' starts with an equals sign which is not allowed.

Comment: I read the [Apache POI documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html): did you try to replace the two ";" with "," (comma)?

Comment: mmmh it seems to be an other problem now but i think for that one it's ok . ich part of the poi did i miss? ty by the ay

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but aren't you missing a '=' ?

- IF((E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)=0;"";E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)
- IF((E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)==0;"";E9*1,5+F9+G9*2/3)

Comment: in excel "=" is used to compare i try and i tell you edit : it does not work

Comment: Ok tnx :) (yes I gave a suggestion just by heart without trying it myself, tnx for clearing this up)